# make ajax present browser cookies to another site

Tags: ajax, authentication, cookies, cross-domain, client-side

I am trying to make an ajax request to get the html of another site and then parse that html for a specific link.  The problem is, this other site requires authentication to be able to view the page.  I am logged into this site in another tab, so I thought that executing the request to get the html client side would also present the necessary cookies and would be validated, but each time I try the request, it fails. I'm not sure if the cookie is HttpOnly.

Is there any way to make a request to get the html of a page in such a way that the request is authenticated by presenting cookies that the browser already presents each time it makes an Http request to this site?

my simple ajax request which works to get html from sites that don't require authentication is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'my url',
       success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
       } 
    });
```

using an ajax request I am able to at least access the page when signed in in another tab using `dataType: "jsonp"`.  By doing this, I am able to view the html of the requested page through the javascript console, but the returned data is `{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}` not the html.  Is there a way to save the response html in a var for parsing?

Here is my updated request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my url',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(data)+ " success");
    },
    error: function(data){
       alert(JSON.stringify(data)+" error")
    }
  });
```

The alert returned is the error alert, but the html is still visible from the console as note.  I think what may be happening is that the link is returning html, but it expects jsonp.  Thoughts?

Comment: This would be a serious security violation if it could work.

Comment: Short answer no, long answer yes :) you could use Curl to submit that page where the for is and then using php dom to parse that page (find this link that you are talking about).

Comment: There are a few exceptions to the same-origin policy that might allow you to do what you want. You'll probably need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: Neither curl nor jsonp will allow access to a cookie from a different site in another tab.

Comment: Consider the danger if this were allowed. You login to your bank in one tab, then go to another site in another tab, and it could access all your banking info.

Comment: what site is in question can you give me url?